# Relay delay LTSpice

Tags: capacitor, ltspice, discharge

I want to delay the time a relay turns off.

I have made a simulation on LTSpice that simulates "how long" it takes for the relay to turn off. The relay is simulated using R2.

I simulated the resistor R1 to vary from 100 ohms to 600 ohms in steps of 100. So for an R1 of 600 ohms, we expect the cap to discharge to 95% in 3 seconds. However, the simulation does not show this. In fact, the discharge time for all R1 values seems to be the same.

Can someone help to determine what is wrong with my simulation?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit 1:

[image]

Comment: You turn off the relay supply voltage (V1) after 4 seconds.

Comment: @G36 Yes I am, but then the cap C1 should then discharge in 3 seconds competely. But it is discharging in a few milliseconds.

Comment: OK, But how can this delay the relay turn-off process if Vcc is already at 0V? It can only delay the base-emitter diode turn off, nothing more.  Also, change the transistor type from NPN to 2N2222.

Comment: @G36 you are correct V1 should be a constant 12V source. I have changed this. I see for a MOSFET this does not work for some reason but for a BJT is does, any thoughts on why?

Comment: For the MOSFET you need a parallel resistor. In parallel with the capacitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you a are shorting the capacitor to GND via the switch resistance (which has the default parameters). Example to set them explicitly:

```
.model SW SW(Ron=1 Roff=1Meg Vt=.5 Vh=-.4)
```

Check if the default threshold is not 0V. If it is, the control voltage shown is never negative.

You can find more details [here](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspiceiv-voltage-controlled-switches.html) and [here](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=S_Voltage_Controlled_Switch).

Comment: Yes it now works, see edit 1! What beautiful screenshot it is.